# How to create a .csv file from a MongoDB tweet database using Python

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, twitter, pymongo

I have created a database in MongoDB with tweets and their sentimental analisys based on tweepy and NLTK. After some experience with Mongoexport to create a CSV file with a dataset from this database stored in the MongoDB, I decided to explore other options more flexibles (specially with other delimiters than "coma"), for example, using the Python itself to generate the CSV file. So far I could print the dataset successfully, correcting the ASCII and Unicode problems and using "|" as delimiter, however I am suffering to create a CSV file from the printing results. The code so far is as follow:

```
import json
import csv
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['twitter_db_stream_1']
collection = db['twitter_collection']
data_python = collection.find({"user.location":{"$exists":True},"user.location":{"$ne":"null"}},{"created_at":1,"text":1,"user.name":1,"user.location":1,"geo.coordinates":1,"sentiment_value":1,"confidence_value":1})

for data in data_python:
    print(data['created_at'],'|',data['text'].encode('utf8'),'|',data['user']['name'].encode('utf8'),'|',data['user']['location'],'|',data['sentiment_value'],'|',data['confidence_value'])
```

The printing results are as follow:

```
Tue Apr 18 06:51:58 +0000 2017 | b'Samsung Galaxy S8 International Giveaway @androidauth #giveaway | b'Matt Torok' | None | pos | 1.0
```

I tried to add the following piece of code using csv.writer, based on some examples from tutorias, however it is not working...

```
csv_file = open('Sentiment_Analisys.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

fields = [["created_at"],["text"],["user.name"],["user.location"],["sentiment_value"],["confidential_value"]] #field names
writer.writerow(fields)

for data in data_python:
    writer.writerow(data['created_at'],data['text'].encode('utf8'),data['user']['name'].encode('utf8'),data['user']['location'],data['sentiment_value'],data['confidence_value'])

csv_file.close()
```

Please, could someone give me some guidance in how to create this CSV file from the printing results above?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you convert everything from `data_python` to a `str` and simply print it with commas?

Comment: Why do you want to create a CSV from print results ? Or is it that you intend to create a '|' delimited CSV?

Comment: Thanks for your comments friends! I need to create this CSV file to use it later on SQL Database. To upload a CSV file as flat file source in SQL, sometimes commas are not effective delimiter, specially if the text on tweet has commas inside.

Comment: Please define what "not working" actually means. From a quick peruse of [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) it would appear to need to wrap your arguments in a list `[]` as in `writer.writerow([data['created_at'],data['text'].encode('utf8'),data['user']['name'].encode('utf8'),data['user']['location'],data['sentiment_value'],data['confidence_value']])`

Comment: And the "delimiter" would be set something like this: `writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)`

Comment: Thanks Neil! I changed as you suggested and the results are:writer.writerow(fields)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have copied a Python 2.x example, but are writing Python 3.x code. The CSV usage is slightly different between these two versions. Also, it is preferable to use a `with` statement whilst dealing with files, which avoids the need to explicitly close the file at the end.

`writerow()` takes a list of strings. Your field names were defined as a list of lists, and your data `writerow()` needed to be converted to use a list as follows:

```
field_names = ["created_at", "text", "user.name", "user.location", "sentiment_value", "confidential_value"]

with open('Sentiment_Analisys.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(field_names)

    for data in data_python:
        csv_output.writerow(
            [
            data['created_at'],data['text'].encode('utf8', 'ignore'),
            data['user']['name'].encode('utf8'),
            data['user']['location'],
            data['sentiment_value'],
            data['confidence_value']
            ])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin, I will try this option!

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks a lot for your suggestion. I applied and it works very fine! The only problem is when I have "emoji" in the tweet text, then I receive the following error message: inline `return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 161-162: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Please, do you have any suggestion to skip the "emoji" characters? I tried to change `utf8` to `unicode_escape` but it doesn`t work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please, could someone give me a guidance on the character issue above? I got an especific charcter that is causing problem, just for reference: `0xB8 =  U+1F4FD FILM PROJECTOR`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One alternative you could try is to force the `encode` to ignore your errors, for example `.encode('utf8', 'ignore')`

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin Evans for your help and support. Thanks a lot for all people who also supported me in this post. Finally I could get a code that is possible to define the type of delimiter and have a little more flexibility when compared with mongoexport.

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down arrows to accept my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Dears, below I would like to share the final code, after getting the support of good friends in stackoverflow. Mongoexport has its advantages, but if you need some flexibility to define your own delimiter to create a CSV file, this code might be interesting. The only problem is that you may lose "emoji" characters since they are converted to text codes through UTF-8 enconding. Anyway, depending on your requirements, such limitation might not be a problem. From previous code posted above, there is a difference in the query `"user.location":{"$ne":"null"}}` that I transported from Mongo Client, but in Python code, you should change `"null"` to `"None"`. I hope my journey to find the right code below, and the kind support of my friends in this post, might be useful for someone in the future! Best Regards!

```
import pymongo
import json
import csv
import numpy
import sys
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['twitter_db_stream_1']
collection = db['twitter_collection']
data_python = collection.find({"user.location":{"$exists":True},"user.location":{"$ne":None}},{"created_at":1,"text":1,"user.name":1,"user.location":1,"sentiment_value":1,"confidence_value":1})

field_names = ["created_at", "text", "user.name", "user.location", "sentiment_value", "confidential_value"]

with open('Sentiment_Analisys.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter="|")
    csv_output.writerow(field_names)

    for data in data_python:
        csv_output.writerow(
            data['created_at'],
            data['text'].encode('utf8', 'ignore'),
            data['user']['name'].encode('utf8'),
            data['user']['location'],
            data['sentiment_value'],
            data['confidence_value']
            ])
```